# how to change placement of input and its value with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using `.html()` to get inputs inside a div and place it in another element using `.html()` again the problem is I cant get it with its value.

```js
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $(".element2").html($(".element1").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js</script>

<div class="element1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter something then clone it!"/>
</div>
<div class="element2"></div>
<button id="myButton">click to clone</button>
```

Comment: If you're trying to *move* a DOM element (as implied by the question title and text) then use `.append()` / `.appendTo()` - if you're trying to *copy* an element (as implied by the text in the code) then use `.clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *copy* one element to another, you can use [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var copy = $(".element1 > *").clone()
```

this will clone all of the elements with .element1 - you can then .append()/.appendTo() these to element2.

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $(".element1 > *").clone().appendTo(".element2");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter something then clone it!"/>
</div>

<div class="element2"></div>
<button id="myButton">click to clone</button>
```

Comment: oh thanks it'll do the job.

Comment: if the element had more items in it should I select them all or the parent element is enough?

Comment: The selector is `.element1 > *` which selects all the elements *inside* .element1 - this is equivalent of your .html() attempt.   It looks like your .element1 and .element2 are *siblings*, so you would not want to clone .element1 and put it *inside* .element2 (otherwise you get `<div class='element2'><div class='element1'><input...`  - wrap all the elements you want to copy into a wrapper div and clone them into another wrapper div (in this case element1/element2 are the wrappers)